# Ajax loading in a container. Problem with height?

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, html

Im having a little trouble, so let me describe you my situation:

I have a site with 2 main areas. A  with naviogation links and a  where the content is shown.

Im using ajax so that when i click on a link these steps happen:

1) the content in #main fadea out

2) the new content is loaded

3) the height of #main is changed

4) the new content is shown.

But for some reasons for some pages, the height of #main wont be properly adjusted. it will be too short, cutting down the content. Ive noticed this only happens the first time, that you load the page, which makes me think its a problem of the browser not being able to calculate properly the height until all the data has been downloaded. But i dont understand why this happens, since the callback function shouldnt start until everything has been loaded, right?

Anyway, heres the code. I hope you guys can give me a hand. Thanks!

```
    $("a:not('.noajax')").live("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        //Load new page
        var link = $(this).attr("href");
        loadpage( link );
    });

    function loadpage(href) {

        //Keep fixed the main container
        var old_height = $(".outermain").innerHeight();
        $("#main").css({"height":(old_height)});

        //Fade out the interior
        $(".outermain").fadeOut(100, function(){
            //Prepare interior to calculate new height
            $(".outermain").css({"display": "block", "visibility": "hidden"});

            //Load new page
            $(".outermain").load(href + " .innermain", function(){

                var new_height = $(".outermain").innerHeight();
                var rolloutspeed = 700 - (new_height / 30);

                rolloutspeed = 600;

                $("#main").animate({"height":new_height}, rolloutspeed , "easeOutBack", function(){
                    $(".outermain").css({"visibility": "visible", "display":"none"}).fadeIn(function(){
                        $("body").removeClass("ajaxblocked");
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }
```

and this is the HTML:

```
<section id="main">
    <div class="outermain">
        <div class="innermain clearfix">

            ...

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the requested html has references to images they wouldn't be downloaded before you calculate the new size, if I'm not mistaken.